# Problema de memoria con un Threading.Timer haciendo ping

Tags: c#

Buenos dias, acabo de iniciarme en el mundo del C# y estoy teniendo algun problema.

La aplicación funciona bien, pero el consumo de memoria crece demasiado y llega un punto que termina desbordando.

Es un formulario, que cada 10 segundos consulta 3 direcciones IP haciendo ping y devuelve si esta bien o no. Todo ello se hace con un Timer. La comprobacion tambien se puede hacer con 3 botones.

El problema es el que comento, que el uso de memoria no para de crecer, y  no encuentro la manera de que eso pare.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace EjemploPing
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            System.Threading.Timer tmr = new System.Threading.Timer(Tick, "tick...", 10000, 1000);


        }
        public void Tick(object data)
        {
            // Esto se ejecuta en un hilo combinado
            //ComprobarPing("192.168.0.173", label1);
            ejecutar();


        }


        private void ejecutar()
        {
            ComprobarPing("192.168.0.110", label1);
            ComprobarPing("192.168.0.249", label2);
            ComprobarPing("192.168.0.248", label3);
        }

        public Boolean ComprobarPing(String ip,Label lb)
        {
            if ((new Ping().Send(ip, 2).Status.ToString()).Equals("Success"))
            {

               lb.BackColor = Color.Green;
               return true;
            }
            else
            {
                lb.BackColor = Color.Red;
                return false;
            }
        }
        private void Comprobar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComprobarPing("192.168.0.110",label1);
        }

        private void Comprobar2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComprobarPing("192.168.0.249", label2);
        }

        private void Comprobar3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComprobarPing("192.168.0.248", label3);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

En principio tu código es muy sencillo y el único problema que puedo apreciar es que cada vez estás creando un objeto `Ping` que es posible que no esté liberando recursos correctamente. En todos los objetos de tipo `IDisposable` siempre es bueno utilizar una estructura `using` de tal manera que al terminar con la instancia, todos los recursos sean liberados.

En tu caso yo probaría a modificar el método `ComprobarPing` de la siguiente manera:

```
public Boolean ComprobarPing(String ip, Label lb)
{
    using (var ping = new Ping())
    { 
        if (ping.Send(ip, 2).Status.ToString().Equals("Success"))
        {

            lb.BackColor = Color.Green;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            lb.BackColor = Color.Red;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Prueba esto a ver si asi se soluciona tu problema de memoria.